# How to make PDF file to be downloadable in HTML 5 link

Tags: html

I'm using FTP client and just put pdf file on the server in the same place where index.html file exist. Then I create href link just like below:

```
<a href="myfile.pdf" download class=" btn btn-lg btn-outline">
   <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download file
</a>
```

And when I click on the link then my browser is trying download pdf file but it return info: "failure - no file". Can somebody explain my what I'm doing wrong? How to make pdf file downloadable?

Comment: If you put the link to the PDF in the address bar does it download?

Comment: Are you sure your file is on the server and readable? What that exact name?

Comment: Exact name is just "CV.pdf"

Comment: Then you need to make `href="CV.pdf"` and can set `download` to `download="myfile.pdf"` though not every browser will obey it.

Comment: Yes, this is elementary. I've changed name to href="CV.pdf". Btw when I run my page on local machine then I can download pdf. But only on the server is problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <a href="myfile.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
        Download file
    </a>
```

Actually it should work. May your IIS does not contain *.pdf mime type, or name is incorrect.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not working. Mozilla Firefox send communicate: "this page is no exist"